# HERE Matrix Routing API - "Method not allowed for this action"

Tags: python-requests, here-api

I am trying to get a [reference example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/matrix-routing-api/dev_guide/topics/modes/region-mode.html) working, but the API throws a 405 error:

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {
    "apiKey": <API_KEY>,
    "origins": [
        {"lat": 52.52103, "lng": 13.41268},
        {"lat": 52.51628, "lng": 13.37771},
        {"lat": 52.47342, "lng": 13.40357}
    ],
    "regionDefinition": {
        "type": "boundingBox",
        "north": 52.53,
        "south": 52.46,
        "west": 13.35,
        "east": 13.42
    },
    "matrixAttributes": ["distances"]
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
```

However, this gives

```
{"error":"Method not allowed for this action","error_description":"Method not allowed for this action"}
```

My `r.url` is https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?apiKey=API_KEY&origins=lat&origins=lng&origins=lat&origins=lng&origins=lat&origins=lng&regionDefinition=type&regionDefinition=north&regionDefinition=south&regionDefinition=west&regionDefinition=east&matrixAttributes=distances

This obviously looks wrong, so I tried modifying my code to

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=json.dumps(payload))
```

This yields an `r.url` of [https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?%7B%22apiKey%22:%20%22API_KEY%22,%20%22origins%22:%20[%7B%22lat%22:%2052.52103,%20%22lng%22:%2013.41268%7D,%20%7B%22lat%22:%2052.51628,%20%22lng%22:%2013.37771%7D,%20%7B%22lat%22:%2052.47342,%20%22lng%22:%2013.40357%7D],%20%22regionDefinition%22:%20%7B%22type%22:%20%22boundingBox%22,%20%22north%22:%2052.53,%20%22south%22:%2052.46,%20%22west%22:%2013.35,%20%22east%22:%2013.42%7D,%20%22matrixAttributes%22:%20[%22distances%22]%7D](https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?%7B%22apiKey%22:%20%22API_KEY%22,%20%22origins%22:%20%5B%7B%22lat%22:%2052.52103,%20%22lng%22:%2013.41268%7D,%20%7B%22lat%22:%2052.51628,%20%22lng%22:%2013.37771%7D,%20%7B%22lat%22:%2052.47342,%20%22lng%22:%2013.40357%7D%5D,%20%22regionDefinition%22:%20%7B%22type%22:%20%22boundingBox%22,%20%22north%22:%2052.53,%20%22south%22:%2052.46,%20%22west%22:%2013.35,%20%22east%22:%2013.42%7D,%20%22matrixAttributes%22:%20%5B%22distances%22%5D%7D)

This also doesn't look right, so I tried the simplest example

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?apiKey=API_KEY&async=false&regionDefinition=world&profile=truckFast'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
```

This yields an `r.url` of https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?apiKey=API_KEY&async=false&regionDefinition=world&profile=truckFast

In all of these examples, the API still returns

```
{"error":"Method not allowed for this action","error_description":"Method not allowed for this action"}
```

Why is this happening?

In case it matters, my `requests.__version__` is 2.27.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was indeed using GET rather than POST. However, posting a more complete answer with code examples, to resolve the questions around how to set the payload, etc.

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?apiKey=<API_KEY>&async=false'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

payload = {
    "origins": [
        {"lat": 52.52103, "lng": 13.41268},
        {"lat": 52.51628, "lng": 13.37771},
        {"lat": 52.47342, "lng": 13.40357}
    ],
    "regionDefinition": {
        "type": "boundingBox",
        "north": 52.53,
        "south": 52.46,
        "west": 13.35,
        "east": 13.42
    },
    "matrixAttributes": ["distances"]
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2))
```

This results in

```
{
  "matrixId": "fdaa07ea-f8d9-4b3f-a410-9c3b2d54e464",
  "matrix": {
    "numOrigins": 3,
    "numDestinations": 3,
    "distances": [
      0,
      2924,
      7258,
      3221,
      0,
      7710,
      7333,
      7721,
      0
    ]
  },
  "regionDefinition": {
    "type": "boundingBox",
    "west": 13.35,
    "south": 52.46,
    "east": 13.42,
    "north": 52.53
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit matrix for route calculation using POST method:

```
https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?regionDefinition=world&profile=truckFast&apiKey=
```

Also please refer to Matrix routing API Examples